# best way to pull pictures for an item, from a separate table, in django

Tags: mysql, django, image

Im having a hard time deciding what is the best way to pull pictures from a separate table, for a certain item.

In django, I have two tables:

```
class item(models.Model):
    title..
    descr..

class item_pic(models.Model):
    item=models.ForeignKey(item)
    pic=models.ImageField...
```

Im displaying the item.title and item.descr in a div, and in the same div I want to pull the pictures.

So far I've tried creating a template filter like item|getPics which returns a list of the pics for that item.

```
{% for pic in item|getPics %} <img src="/uploads/{{pic.pic}}"> {%endfor%}
```

In the end I got rid of this since it was firing too many sql queries

Right now I finished pulling the pictures through ajax, the only downside here is that the images take some time to appear. And I assume is the same number of sql queries (only that django debug toolbar doesnt see them since they are fired up in the background).

How would you approach this? Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You can use `select_related` to query a item and its images in `views`,then render them in the template https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related

Comment: thanks! i knew about it but never thought of using it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `select_related()` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related)) to get the image objects together with the items.

It would look like this:

```
item = item.objects.select_related().get(...)
```

This means you won't get additional database queries when you're retrieving the `item_pics`.

As a final note, it's better to capitalize the names of classes as this is convention in Python/Django.

Comment: thanks Simeon! i just tested this in the interpreter and i can access the pictures through item.item_pic_set.filter() ... great stuff! Is there somewhere any docs with python/django conventions, I have no problem in rewriting my code to be clean as whistle!

Comment: Python developers mostly refer to the PEP 8 coding style guidelines: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/ which describe how Python should (could) be formatted. Readability remains the most important thing so sometimes you should deviate from the rules.